# AsyncTask from Activity Class

Tags: java, android

I am using this class to download txt file

```
class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void,String> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Item> doInBackground(String... params) {
    try{
        URL url = new URL("myurl");
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null){
        }

        in.close();
        return str;
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e){}
    catch (IOException e){}

    return null;

}

protected void onPostExecute(Strin str) {

}
```

this is how i call this class from my activity:

```
new RetreiveFeedTask().execute();
```

And i want to know if there is a way to pass out this result to the activity that make the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a listener which you'll pass in the constructor of your AsyncTask. In your onPostExecute you just call this listener.

Something like that:

> ```
> public interface OnTaskCompleteListener { 
>      void onTaskComplete(String result); 
> }
>
> protected void onPostExecute(String str) {
>     onTaskCompleteListener.onTaskComplete(str);
> }
> ```